# Seasonal trend decomposition in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, statsmodels

I would like to use the STL (Seasonal-Trend-Loess) approach implemented in `statsmodels` [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.STL.html) to pull out the seasonal component of some time series data. Just one problem... the code for the STL doesn't seem to exist. I've reinstalled `statsmodels`, checked their github, and gone through the actual .py files... can't find it in `statsmodels.tsa.seasonal` at all. Only `seasonal_decompose` which is not as good.

Any suggestions on where I might find the code needed for STL? Or good alternatives?

Comment: What version of Statsmodels are you using? STL was only introduced in v0.11

Comment: That was it! I thought I'd installed the latest version but for some reason my Anaconda only had v.0.10... updating the package library there fixed it. Thanks @cfulton !